# How can I do return_sequences for a stacked LSTM model with PyTorch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch

I have a Tensorflow / Keras model with:

```
        self.model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(lstm1_size, input_shape=(
            seq_length, feature_dim), return_sequences=True)))
        self.model.add(BatchNormalization())
        self.model.add(Dropout(0.2))

        self.model.add(Bidirectional(
            LSTM(lstm2_size, return_sequences=True)))
        self.model.add(BatchNormalization())
        self.model.add(Dropout(0.2))

        # BOTTLENECK HERE

        self.model.add(Bidirectional(
            LSTM(lstm3_size, return_sequences=True)))
        self.model.add(BatchNormalization())
        self.model.add(Dropout(0.2))

        self.model.add(Bidirectional(
            LSTM(lstm4_size, return_sequences=True)))
        self.model.add(BatchNormalization())
        self.model.add(Dropout(0.2))

        self.model.add(Bidirectional(
            LSTM(lstm5_size, return_sequences=True)))
        self.model.add(BatchNormalization())
        self.model.add(Dropout(0.2))

        self.model.add(Dense(feature_dim, activation='linear'))
```

How do I create a stacked PyTorch model with the `return_sequences`? My understanding of `return_sequences` is that it returns the "output" of each layer of LSTM's which are then fed into the next layer.

How would I accomplish this with PyToch?

Comment: What exactly are you unsure about? In the current state, this question is way to vague, and not showing any implementation efforts from your side. If you are looking for a definite conversion guide, I would go via the [ONNX](https://github.com/onnx) format, which is the only link I feel comfortable pointing to that is not a biased resource. Then again, ONNX is not really suited to also reproduce training, I'm afraid, as it is mostly for sharing the model architecture.

Comment: Updated the question to be more specific

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PyTorch always returns sequences.

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#lstm

[image]

**Example:**

```
import torch as t

batch_size = 2
time_steps = 10
features = 2
data = t.empty(batch_size, time_steps, features).normal_()

lstm = t.nn.LSTM(input_size=2, hidden_size=3, bidirectional=True, batch_first=True)

output, (h_n, c_n) = lstm(data)
[output.shape, h_n.shape, c_n.shape]
```

> [torch.Size([2, 10, 6]), torch.Size([2, 2, 3]), torch.Size([2, 2, 3])]

```
class Net(t.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.lstm_1 = t.nn.LSTM(input_size=2, hidden_size=3, bidirectional=True, batch_first=True)
        self.lstm_2 = t.nn.LSTM(input_size=2*3, hidden_size=4, bidirectional=True, batch_first=True)

    def forward(self, input):
        output, (h_n, c_n) = self.lstm_1(input)
        output, (h_n, c_n) = self.lstm_2(output)
        return output

net = Net()

net(data).shape
```

> torch.Size([2, 10, 8])

Comment: Yes. If you'd like the final element, you should take `output[:,-1,:]` with `batch_first=True`, and `output[-1,:,:]` with `batch_first=False`.